# Select rows with second highest value for each ID repeated multiple times

Tags: postgresql

```
Id values
1 10
1 20
1 30
1 40
2 3
2 9
2 0
3 14
3 5 
3 7
```

Answer should be

```
Id values
1 30
2 3
3 7
```

I tried as below

```
Select distinct 
    id,
    (select max(values) 
     from table 
     where values not in(select ma(values) from table)
     )
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more info, please see How to Ask and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`row_number` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). This adds a column with a row count for each group (in your case the ids). In a subquery you are able to ask for the second row of each group.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a370b181e65cee2971946d1003307095)

```
SELECT
    id, values
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY values DESC)
    FROM
        table
) s
WHERE row_number = 2
```